# d3.js - 3D view in pie chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been working on pie chart using d3.js . Everything works fine but I am stuck in a 3D animation. I require a 3D view just like http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/3d-pie/

Please give me your views, is it even possible to achieve this with d3.js ?

Comment: Its possible but I think it would be more of a pain than its worth...you'd have to draw the second circle manually to give the 3d effect as far as I know

Comment: yes I have already tried creating two circles, but its not giving the perfect look as color overlapping of the slices are not proper at some ends. So its not that picture perfect look that I need.

Answer (score 1):

WEll i have unique answer to it. i will help you make it 3d without any third party javascript
If you've used Adobe illustrator, you'd know that it has filters which can implement any svg element to 3d

I have exploited that property to make it 3D

```
<defs>
        <filter id="filters" >
        <feFlood flood-color="#CCCCCC" result="COLOR-red" /> 
        <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="-3" in="SourceAlpha" result="STROKE_10" /> 
        <feConvolveMatrix order="10,10" divisor="1" kernelMatrix="
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
        0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
        0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
        0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1" in="STROKE_10" result="BEVEL_20" />
        <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" in="BEVEL_0" result="BEVEL_25"/>   
        <feComposite operator="out" in="BEVEL_25" in2="STROKE_10" result="BEVEL_30"/>    
        <feComposite in="COLOR-red" in2="BEVEL_30" operator="in" result="BEVEL_40" />    
        <feMerge result="BEVEL_50">
        <feMergeNode in="BEVEL_40" />    
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" /> </feMerge>  
        </filter>
        </defs>
```

embed this code to your svg and add attribute `filter="url(#filters)"` to the element you want to put filter on like
if there is element like `<g></g>` just add `<g class="whatever" filter="url(#filter)"></g>`
you'll get 3D effect . Rest you need to play with the code to change the color and depth and everything

Answer (score 0):

you can use google chart as well its 3d chart
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

Answer (score -3):

I would highly suggest to use the Highcharts for kind of pie-chart you are looking for. I have recently implemented in one of my app..You can check it here:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic